# Spark Scala traverse and transform nested struct list

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, struct, nested

I am new to Spark functions and Scala. I want to traverse and transform nested struct list  like below:

Ex:
Input:

```
"a":[{
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "unitedStates": {
                "employees": [{
                    "name": "Amy",
                    "role": "janitor"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bart",
                    "role": "admin"
                }]
            },
            "unitedKingdom": {
                "employees": [{
                    "name": "Cat",
                    "role": "janitor"
                },
                {
                    "name": "David",
                    "role": "engineer"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

```
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- unitedStates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- employees: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- unitedKingdom: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- employees: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 ....
```

Expected output:

```
a.b.c.employees.janitors: [{Amy, unitedStates}, {Cat, unitedKingdom}]
a.b.c.employees.admins: [{Bart, unitedStates}]
a.b.c.employees.engineers: [{David, unitedKingdom}]
```

I am having a hard time trying to read and extract struct field key names like `unitedStates`, `unitedKingdom` which can be of any country values. This is what I have so far:

```
val testExpr = "transform(a.b.c, x -> x.key)"
inputDF.withColumn("test", expr(testExpr)).show(false)
```

Got `Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field key in unitedStates, unitedKingdom`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Right now, it is not entirely clear what you want your output to be. Do you want to extract a dataframe with arrays in a column? Do you want to extract arrays? Also, it helps to add the code how you created your `inputDF` so that the reviewers don't have to recreate it themselves, making it more likely that your question will get a great response :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode json arrays into DataFrame columns.

This is to get you the general idea:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


input = {"a":[{
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "unitedStates": {
                "employees": [{
                    "name": "Amy",
                    "role": "janitor"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bart",
                    "role": "admin"
                }]
            },
            "unitedKingdom": {
                "employees": [{
                    "name": "Cat",
                    "role": "janitor"
                },
                {
                    "name": "David",
                    "role": "engineer"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}]
}
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([input]))
df1= df.selectExpr('inline(a.b.c)')

countries = df1.schema.names
dfs = []
for country in countries:
    tempDf = df1.select(df1[country]).withColumnRenamed(country, 'data').withColumn('country', lit(country))
    tempDf = tempDf.select(tempDf['country'], explode(tempDf['data.employees']).alias('employee')).select('country', 'employee.name', 'employee.role' ) 
    dfs.append(tempDf)

df_complete = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
df_complete.show(truncate=False)
```

And the output is:

```
+-------------+-----+--------+
|country      |name |role    |
+-------------+-----+--------+
|unitedKingdom|Cat  |janitor |
|unitedKingdom|David|engineer|
|unitedStates |Amy  |janitor |
|unitedStates |Bart |admin   |
+-------------+-----+--------+
```